# How to do a PHP While in a query?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.

1. Customers
2. Orders

I want to see the latest order for every customers. I have done this using two different queries:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Customers"; 
$rslt = mysql_query($sql);
WHILE( $row =  mysql_fect_object($rslt)) 
{
   $sql_order = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE customer_id = $row->customer_id 
                 ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 0,1";
   ................
   ................
}
```

Output is perfect but I have to write PHP code.

Is there any way I can just output the query results, without help of PHP code?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: And you don't need to shout. Rly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No.

The database contains all the data. The PHP code requests a specific chunk of data and must then format it into a human readable form. You can keep the amount of PHP to a minimum, but you're gonna need it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, how about T-SQL, can T-SQL solve the issue? can I not run both query using a join?

Comment: Oh, yes you can join the queries, but you would still need PHP to output the results, although you can do without the loop. Maybe I misunderstood the question?

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have php installed, you can pipe the query to mysql, directly from a prompt

```
echo "SELECT * FROM Customers" | mysql database_name -uusername -ppassword
```

[Update 2011-08-11 11:30]

To combine your 2 querys above in a bash script:

```
echo "SELECT customer_id FROM Customers" | mysql database_name -uusername -ppassword | xargs -I "{}" echo "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE customer_id = {} ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 0,1" | mysql database_name -uusername -ppassword
```

or a more readable version, replaced pipes whit rowbreaks

```
echo "SELECT customer_id FROM Customers"
mysql database_name -uusername -ppassword
xargs -I "{}" echo "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE customer_id = {} ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 0,1"
mysql database_name -uusername -ppassword
```

Comment: i read the question "Is there any way I can just output the query results, without help of PHP code?"

Comment: Thank you very much, do you have any query example to solve my issue

Comment: sure, added a few more rows to my answer above

Comment: Thanks again, can I run that query inside MYSQL query browser? Actually I am looking for a fresh query which will be run on MYSQL browser with help of PHP code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get out the newest order for each customer in a single query, you could use:

```
SELECT Orders.* 
FROM Orders 
LEFT JOIN Orders AS newer_orders ON (newer_orders.customer_id = Orders.customer_id AND newer_orders.date > Orders.date)
WHERE newer_orders.customer_id IS NULL
ORDER BY Orders.customer_id
```

you may need to replace ".date" whit the column you wanted to use to sort the newest on, at your query you missed that "ORDER BY DESC"

The query joins the table whit a copy of it self on rows whit newer orders of the same customer_id, and then in the where i filter out the rows that don't have a newer_order, so it only shows the newest ones

Comment: how about if i want to add customer details with the same query?

Comment: it takes a bit long time to execute this query

Comment: to also include Customers-data: "SELECT Customers.*, Orders.* FROM Customers LEFT JOIN Orders USING(customer_id) LEFT JOIN Orders AS newer_orders ON (newer_orders.customer_id = Orders.customer_id AND newer_orders.date > Orders.date)
WHERE newer_orders.customer_id IS NULL
ORDER BY Customers.customer_id", even whit index this way is ofen slower then runing multiple querys, so i hope you have an index on Orders.customer_id

Comment: Dear Puggan, I have done that before you post, but you are a star, you saved my hours!